# How to match strings that start and end with the same character, but have an odd number of letters?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to formulate a regex that identifies strings that begin and end with 'B" but also have an odd number of letters overall. So far I have the following:

Strings that start and end with B:

```
^B.*B$
```

I am not sure how to get it so that it only accepts an odd number of letter. For even numbers it's easy:

```
^B(..)*B$
```

But odd is throwing me a little

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be almost the same:

```
^B.(..)*B$
```

Comment: arghhhh, that was so easy! Thanks